# Не стартует веб-сервер на archlinux

Tags: apache, lamp, archlinux, php

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь установить веб-сервер на archlinux [по этому мануалу](http://root-inform.blogspot.com/2012/01/lamp-archlinux.html).

При запуске `apache` выдает вот эту ошибку:

> [root@sdushor ~]# /etc/rc.d/httpd start:: Starting Apache Web Server                                            [BUSY] httpd: Syntax error on line 94 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Can't locate API module structure `php_module' in file /etc/httpd/modules/[libphp5.so](http://libphp5.so): /etc/httpd/modules/[libphp5.so](http://libphp5.so): undefined symbol: php_module                                                                             [FAIL]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема.

Скорее всего, проблема в том, что apache и php не были корректно установлены. Решение - переустановить из родного репозитория. Вот [так](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LAMP_%28%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%29)